# How should one interpret the DC component of a sound pressure wave?

Tags: signal-processing, microphone, pyaudio

I'm using a microphone with the Pyaudio package to record a constant 1000hz tune. Upon plotting, I noticed that there is instability in the DC component of the signal in the few first chunks of the recording. In other word, the moving average of the signal is not near 0 in the beginning of the recording before settling down to 0.

I wonder if this is due to the transient behavior of the sound card or microphone, and that I should ignore the first few chunks for my analysis.